# Database schema, containing account information

Tags: sql, database, web-applications, rdbms

everyone.
My current goal is to develop database structure for web application-based control system of internet-provider. It is a learning task with following requirements:

The **administrator** registers the **subscriber** in the system. System provides **services** list (Telephone, Internet, Cable TV, IP-TV etc) and different **subscription plans** for each service. 
A subscriber can select one or more services with a certain **subscription plans** for each service. A subscriber has an **account** and can 
replenish the balance. The funds from the account are removed, depending on the selected **subscription plans**. If the funds on account are insufficient, the system blocks the user.

The system administrator has the rights to:
add, delete or edit the **subscription plans**;
register, block or unblock the user.

I think, that all words, highlighted with bold are considered to be entities.

I developed following schema:

[image: schema]

And now I have few questions:

1. Is it OK to have different tables for subscriber and account, or should they be merged(one subscriber can only have one account)?
2. Should current balance be stored as column in the account table, or should it be calculated each time?
3. Is it OK to have a table with only ID column?

Any critique and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please, format your question as list.

Answer (score 0):

1. They must be merged, because your model allows links "one subscriber - many accounts".
2. It's depends on your use cases. For optimization you can add trigger on `incoming_payment` and update  `subscriber.balance`. So you can very quickly build reports.
3. Table that contains only generated ID looks bad. In your model service must have property type (Telephone, Internet, Cable TV, IP-TV etc).